# Display Name of Connected Cell Tower

Tags: cellular-radio

On older Nokia phones, the name of the cell tower you were connected to was displayed, often the name of the neighborhood you were in. Is there a way to view this data now?

Answer (score 2):

[OpenSignal](http://opensignal.com/) have an [App](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.staircase3.opensignal) which will give you a lot of information about the tower that you are connected to, which direction it is in, which other towers are available in the area, including ones on other networks, etc.

- Free App
- Gives all the information that you have asked for
- Allows you to monitor your coverage through the day
- Allows connection testing
- If you are willing to share your data it is added to the data available to everybody.

[image]